# BASH: Calculating given operations

Tags: bash, bc

I want to calculate a given string in Bash. For example, given the string

```
(1+4)*2
```

I want the answer

```
10
```

I tried:

```
read x
echo $[$x]
```

It works fine for integer arithmetic, but I realize that it isn't working for floating point numbers: with the string

```
x=1/2
```

running

```
echo $[$x]
```

yields `0`, but I want `0.5`.

What should I do to get over this problem?

Comment: You can use: `bc -l <<< "(1+4)*2"` OR `bc -l <<< "1/2"`

Comment: can you write full line with using x?

Comment: @anubhava: Make this an answer!